# Why are the boxers so similar to Homer and Bart? Is it coincidental?

Tags: the-simpsons

In "Moaning Lisa," Bart and Homer get involved in video-game boxing. The boxers displayed in the game look very similar to Homer and Bart. Production-wise this makes sense, as it eliminates the need to explain which character is controlling which boxer, etc. But is there a canon explanation why there is a similarity? Or is it a coincidence?

Comment: FWIW, ["Moaning Lisa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moaning_Lisa) is S1E6: Feb 1990.  That predates any user-customizable avatar action video games I'm aware of by around a decade.  Heck, it's before Eternal September, so I don't know how widely-known _chat_ avatars would have been.  What I'm saying is that there's nothing in the computer gaming state-of-the-art at that time for it to be based on, so it basically has to be a viewer convenience.

Comment: It's certainly possible that the Simpsons' universe is more advanced than the "real" one in terms of such technology.

Comment: This feels like one of those questions where "because it's a cartoon" is a fine answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia, citing the episode's DVD commentary, [states that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moaning_Lisa#Production)

> The designs of the boxers in the video game Homer and Bart play were loosely based on Homer and Bart

So from a production standpoint, the resemblance was deliberate, and presumably done so that the viewers would know who was controlling which character. In-universe, though, it was almost certainly coincidence.

There's another, more prominent example of these intentional design similarities: Matt Groening [designed Krusty the Clown to resemble Homer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krusty_the_Clown#Creation), to create a "satirical conceit" in which Bart "had no respect for his father, but worshipped a clown who looked exactly like his father". Yet in-universe, the resemblance between Homer and Krusty is pure coincidence. In-universe, the resemblance between them forms part of the plot of the episode "Homie the Clown", but is otherwise coincidental.

Comment: `In-universe, though, it was almost certainly coincidence.` It's not impossible for them to have picked characters that resemble themselves, assuming there are more than two boxers in the game.

Comment: Also, Homer was initially slated to _be_ Krusty the Clown - specifically to subvert the "satirical conceit" in which Bart loathes his father (as Homer) yet unknowingly looks up to him as well (as Krusty). The planned storyline was cancelledand instead Homer trained to be a replacement Krusty in "Homie the Clown". You can sort of see Krusty look more like Homer in makeup [on his first appearance in the show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krusty_the_Clown#/media/File:Krustys_first_appearance.png)